# mouse sharing using barrier

Tags: mouse

so I have installed [barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier) on my windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04.2 lts machines, to use as a software kvm switch, and the ubuntu side just hangs at "Barrier is starting" when running as a client from my ubuntu machine and server on windows.  Windows side shows started and running? The graphical server config layout shows my linux machine but the linux machine is still just "barrier is starting"  just a fyi super basic knowledge here so the easiest fixes are the best ones for me? Thank you!

Comment: What is barrier? How did you install it in Ubuntu? If you used a command, please copy and paste the command as well as the output of the command (if any) in your question. Then format the pasted output as code using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that you probably have not added the client's name to the server configuration. If you check the log files on the client, you should see the repeated message about the server refusing connections for your computer's name.

The solution is to add your client's details to the server's configuration:

- From the client's screen, above where you entered the server's IP, you will find your "Screen name"
- On the server, click "Configure Server", then drag a new screen to appear next to the existing screen.
- double click on the new screen
- enter as a screen name whatever name you would like to call your client
- add an alias for the screen - this must be the exact name from your client's "Screen name" of step 1.
- save your changes, and reload the server

Comment: thanks man, I hit this issue as well, the fix step for me is to add a CORRECT alias for my client on the server side~!

Comment: For me the solution was in the error logs